# Generate new table base on date sub?

Tags: mysql

I have a tables like this.

| Name | Created |
| --- | --- |
| Frank | 20210321 |
| Jack | 20210324 |

And expect output table:

| Name | TaskID |
| --- | --- |
| Frank | Frank-20210321 |
| Frank | Frank-20210322 |
| Frank | Frank-20210323 |
| Frank | Frank-20210324 |
| Jack | Frank-20210324 |

Assume today is 20210324, and How to generate a new table?

What i have tried.

```
SELECT name, concat(name, "-", created)
```

And I know I can use

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2021-03-25', '2021-03-21') as DAYS;
```

To calculate a different days.

But it just simple one task was generate per each line.

Comment: @Akina the latest mysql version, InnoDB eng

Comment: Why `Created` which stores a date is defined as numeric?

Comment: @Akina it's just a key for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT CAST(MIN(Created) AS DATE) d FROM test
         UNION ALL
         SELECT d + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM cte WHERE d < CURRENT_DATE )
SELECT test.name, CONCAT(test.name, '-', DATE_FORMAT(cte.d, '%Y%m%d')) TaskID
FROM cte
JOIN test ON cte.d >= test.Created
ORDER BY TaskID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e086f9ce8ed6b32713f2932549f295c

Comment: Thanks, it works very well. But did you know how to query on version 5.7?

Comment: @FrankAK On 5.7 you must use static generation (using `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION ...`). Or use some service/system table with the numbers. Of course the numbers amount (stored or generated) must be not less than the dates range width (I usually create service table `mysql.numbers` with integers from 0 to 999).